# What are the benefits of using JSF2 resources?

Tags: jsf, resources, jsf-2, facelets

Should I use JSF2 resources instead of plain html like `<link href...` or `url(image.png)`? What are the benefits? For me this is a bit annoying when web-designer creates layout with XHTML, CSS and all that stuff and I need to spend time to replace plain HTML paths and tags to JSF resource tags like`#{resource[...]}`.

Is there any other way? Like to put all CSS/image files in web root and use normal links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice.

The major benefit is that you can declare them on a per-component basis. If you need to include them on every single page anyway, then the benefit is little. But if you need to include component-specific CSS/JS code in for example a composite component which is reused more than once in a single view, then for example an [`<h:outputScript>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) in a composite component would end up in it being included only once instead of that many times as the composite component is been used as would happen with `<script>`. The same applies to the [`@ResourceDependency`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceDependency.html) annotation on real [`UIComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) classes.

Please note that you are not *required* to use JSF2 resources only. Just plain vanilla `<img>`, `<link>`, `<script>`, etc is also perfectly fine. It can even point to the JSF resources folder.